# import slider html into a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, browser, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to import separate .html page that is with a touch slider in the background in my web site page but it not show. I used this:

```javascript
$( ".slide_image" ).load( "test.html" );
```

But it does not work can any one help me to fix this one?

--Edited-- I used Google chrome before. that is the problem it's not working with 
     Google chrome, opera and IE 
     work well safari and Firefox browsers.

Comment: well that little thing is not helping us?

Comment: thank for respond. no I tried lot of time but it not work. is this the correct way import separate html into a div?

Comment: What is not working? Is the path correct? Need more info - you have a URL?

Comment: I'm trying to import test.html file into a .slide_image div, in the test.html file I created background slider. I can create that slider also index.html but I need to create it separate and import it into slide_image div because if I include it into index.html file code going hard to edit

Comment: We need the full code to have a clear picture

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. After the load function completes, check if the HTML from test.html is available using FireBug.
2. Check for console errors.

I'm assuming the `test.html` page has a script tag which includes the JavaScript required for the slideshow. Remove that script tag from there and put it in your caller page.

Comment: ahh thanks it works well with Firefox, I used Google chrome before . that is an problem it's not working with Google chrome, opera and IE work well safari and Firefox browsers.

Comment: there is an error like this "XMLHttpRequest cannot load .../web_page/slider.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "